# Opencv "select timeout" error with camera_capture on vm Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on vm player. I have written a script to connect laptop's webcam. But, I got `select timeout` error with  r`et, frame = video_capture.read()`, although I selected camera from **"removable devices"** section.

When I tried to run script on windows, it was successful.

code: read_video.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

error:

```
 read_video.py 
select timeout
select timeout
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (total() == 0 || data != __null) in Mat, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 500
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_video.py", line 9, in <module>
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:500: error: (-215) total() == 0 || data != __null in function Mat
```

How can I solve it?